# MySQL: In which case should I choose MyIsam over innoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

InnoDB seems almost entirely superior but in what case should I go for MyIsam?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb). Anyway, you have some pretty good answers there, check them out. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyIsam is much faster if you don't plan on having lots of traffic/transactions.

The problem with MyIsam is that it locks the table when it's in use, whereas innodb just locks the row. Innodb is a bit slower because of this, but allows simultaneous access to the same table, so it's more suitable for heavy traffic/transactions.

So, to conclude - if you don't expect your site to be accessing your database that much and it's low traffic, then myIsam is usually the best option for speed.